# Groovy programming with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I'm new to groovy. I've written the simple program which is used in elasticsearch watcher condition, but it is getting an exception `MissingMethodException` after the `FOR IN` log statement.

```
FOR IN
[2016-09-08 16:42:42,654][ERROR][watcher.condition.script ] [elk-node] failed to execute [script] condition for [testwatch_12-2016-09-08T16:42:42.608Z]
ScriptException[failed to run file script [validateScore] using lang [groovy]]; nested: MissingMethodException[No signature of method: de52a242cfec68298fc9cbef740d5b0e4d4112b0.$() is applicable for argument types: (de52a242cfec68298fc9cbef740d5b0e4d4112b0$_run_closure1) values: [de52a242cfec68298fc9cbef740d5b0e4d4112b0$_run_closure1@31787094]
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), run(), run(), any(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), any(groovy.lang.Closure)];
        at org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptEngineService$GroovyScript.run(GroovyScriptEngineService.java:320)
        at org.elasticsearch.watcher.condition.script.ExecutableScriptCondition.doExecute(ExecutableScriptCondition.java:67)
        at org.elasticsearch.watcher.condition.script.ExecutableScriptCondition.execute(ExecutableScriptCondition.java:54)
        at org.elasticsearch.watcher.condition.script.ExecutableScriptCondition.execute(ExecutableScriptCondition.java:36)
        at org.elasticsearch.watcher.execution.ExecutionService.executeInner(ExecutionService.java:368)
        at org.elasticsearch.watcher.execution.ExecutionService.execute(ExecutionService.java:273)
        at org.elasticsearch.watcher.execution.ExecutionService$WatchExecutionTask.run(ExecutionService.java:438)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
```

```groovy
def thres = ${threshold}
println "${ctx.payload.hits.hits[0]._score}"
def result = false
def score = ${hit._score}


for(hit in ctx.payload.hits.hits){
  println "FOR IN"
  if (${score} > ${thres}) {
    println "Inside Condition IF"
    result = true
  }
}
```

ElasticSearch Watcher Condision

> "condition": {
>         "script" : { "file" : "validateScore", "lang": "groovy", "params" : { "threshold" : 1.09 } }
>       },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI this may be a better solution for you

```
result = ctx.payload.hits.hits.any { score > thres }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you define `thres` and `score` as variables in the script you don't need to use `${}` form to get their values

replace `if (${score} > ${thres})` with `if (score > thres)`